How do I find the actual vs difference for calculating backpropagation on the first hidden layer in a AI with 2 hidden layers?
I have a simple AI built out in an Excel sheet for testing. It has 4 inputs, 1 hidden layer with 4 Neurons, and 4 outputs. I am trying to add a second hidden layer, with 4 Neurons. I am using backpropagation. I understand the point where one hidden layer's weights and bias are adjusted based off the error from the output sigmoid vs the actual desired output. But how do I determine that for the hidden layer prior in a 2 hidden layer AI? Does the backpropagation need to adjust the weights and bias in the output layer first?
I am new to learning AI and want to understand it from the ground up, so please bare with me! I do not fully understand the math symbols involved in all this, my background is in programming, so some simple guidance in non-calculus language would be really helpful. I am also reverse engineering this in SQL. I started with an excel sheet from this site that is only 2 inputs and outputs, and I am expanding on it, but is essentially the same.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1273000/Machine-Learning-in-Excel
I have used ChatGPT and tried to read and understand from various sites and have gotten this far but this is really stumping me.
Thanks!

I don't understand this question "But how do I determine that for the hidden layer prior in a 2 hidden layer AI?" Are you asking how do you determine the weights for this new layer you want to add? The general answer is: backpropagation. But I suppose you're asking for the formulas and an explanation of how back-propagation would work for a 2-hidden layer NN, right?

There is a video on backpropagation by a Stanford grad who posts about math under the name 3blue1brown. I recommend it. His videos have a lot of helpful visualizations to build intuition around the math.

@nbro Yes thats correct. I understand how it works in a 1 hidden layer network, the idea being you are taking the difference between the output vs desired, and doing some maths and applying it backwards. But in a multi layer network, does this mean I take some output vs desired in between HL 1 and HL 2? Do I run backpropagation on HL 2, then somehow look at what HL 1 is outputting vs a desired in order to activate HL 2 properly? Just confused on this part.

@JimMcGaw thank you I will definitely be taking a look at this! Appreciate it!
